# Reference both spill and "regular" cells in spill formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to using array formulas that create a spill range.
I tried referencing a spill range and a regular, non-spill range within a formula, but had trouble getting the non-spill reference to follow the rows of the spill range it creates.

For instance I have the following data:

|  | Column A (spill range) | Column B (spill range) | Column C (regular data) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 1 | 10 | 5 |
| Row 2 | 2 | 15 | 3 |
| Row 3 | 3 | 20 | 10 |

Now I want to create a range of =(A1*B1)/C1 copied down to the end of the range as a spill range.

Desired Spill-result:

| Spill result |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 10 |
| 6 |

I tried `=(A1#*B1#)/@C:C` which will result in multiplying all results with the value of `C1` instead of using C2 for the 2nd spill.
I then tried losing the `@` but that's referencing all cells in column C.
Referencing C# does not work as it's not a spill range.

I manage to get correct referencing indirectly by using
`=(A1#*B1#)/FILTER(C:C,A:A<>"")`
(just came up with the solution writing this question)

Is there a simpler, more elegant way to reference the non-spill range so it behaves just like referencing a spill range?

Comment: Why do you need it as a spill range if column C won't spill?

Comment: FWIW, you could use either `OFFSET(B1#,0,1)` or `INDEX(B1#:C1,0,2)` for example.

Comment: @,Rory I want a report that changes if the reffered (spill)ranges change. One column has manual entry, but should be considered in the report. It's different data than my example, but it's about the idea of referencing to the non-spilled range within a spill formula.

Comment: I like the INDEX-solution you provided. Something to remember

Comment: @Rory if you post your suggestions as answer I'll accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either:

```
OFFSET(B1#,0,1)
```

or:

```
INDEX(B1#:C1,0,2)
```

for the latter part. `OFFSET` is volatile but if you don't have too many of them should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

[image: referencing ordinary and spill ranges in single function/cell]

i.e. allowing for my nifty 'relabelling' (so that the box would actually fit in excel in decent fashion) - per accompanying screenshot, all you need to do is select the relevant cells, and hit enter!  *vide-licit* (excel will automatically 'shrink' your spill ranges with the # sign, and leave the other 'non-spill' ranges as is - no need for @ and certainly no need to 'create' a spoof spill range with index function or something else...

```
=C3#*D3#/E3:E5
```

I've also given a 2nd method as OP specified 'for non-spill to act like spill range' - this is just a std./generic 'wrapper' to 'emulate' the dynamic range functionality that spill ranges enjoy....

```
=C3#*D3#/E3:OFFSET(E3,COUNTA(E:E)-2,0,1,1)
```

[extra characters because it says I need at least 30 extra ignore ignore]...

Comment: OFFSET with COUNTA would not work if the (manual) range would contain an empty value, but this is not the case in my example. The range referencing would not work because the range changes continuously. I liked the simplicity of the INDEX solution provided by Rory.

Comment: It's nice to see the actual ranges change with the spill range in the formula, however both spill ranges need to be the same size to make it work, otherwise the auto updating is lost, but something to remember also.

Comment: RE: spill ranges needing to be same 'length' - sure sure.  Try 'ctrl + t' in any of the input cells to rectify such issues cropping up...

Comment: Good thinking, creating table makes the ranges grow evenly.